# Why Is This Program Not Behaving LIke An Unlimited Input Line - c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, memory-leaks

I was trying to create a C++ program that allows the user to enter how many ever characters he/she likes (as long as the memory can take it), and once they press enter (ASCII Number : 13), the program prints out the whole string of characters entered by the user.

But for some reason, even though the program takes as much input of characters that you give it, it does not print out the whole string of characters entered by the user ... well it just stops running and when I look at my Windows resource monitor it shows that a memory leak has occurred with the program, that gets cleaned up in a few seconds, but I really want to know what is wrong with my program.

Thanks in Advance

Here is my whole source code :

```
    #include<iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
     int main()
     {
       int ctr = 0, n = 10, counter = 0;
       char *stloc = NULL, *ptr = NULL, *cptr = NULL; // creating a NULL pointer
       ptr = new char[n]; // get an array of 10 bytes allocated in heap memory

       while((int)(*ptr) != 13) // Take input till Enter Key is pressed
       {
        if(counter == (n+ctr-1)) // Check if array overflow is going to happen
        {
               ctr+=2; // add two to ctr so that an extra 2 byte space is created in the new char array for a character and '\0'
               cptr = new char[n+ctr];
               strcpy(cptr,ptr);
               delete [] ptr;
               ptr = cptr;
               stloc = ptr;
        }
        *ptr = getche();
        ptr++;   
        counter++;
      }    
      *ptr = '\0';
      cout << endl << stloc;
      delete [] ptr;
      system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting input from the user?  Also why not use `std::string`?  Your whole program could be replaced with `std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);`

Comment: Since you are doing pointer arithmetic to use `ptr` as an iterator, it's a very bad idea to call `delete ptr`.  And since it's not the beginning of your string, it's also a bad idea to call `strcpy(cptr, ptr)` to transfer the memory contents.  Even after all that, you're resetting `ptr` to the beginning of the string after each resize and overwriting the contents.

Comment: The C runtime library convert the <kdb>Return</kdb> into a newline character (`'\n'`) and its ASCII code is 10 not 13... And at the moment you test *ptr, ptr points to an uninitialized value! At first run, nothing has been read and on next ones, you have just incremented ptr... Unless you have special requirements, stop using conio and follow C++ tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `std::string` and `std::getline` to read an entire line of text. (Which will at the first newline character.) A simple program capable of doing this would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string myLine;
  getline(cin, myLine);
  cout<<myLine<<endl;
}
```

For further reading, you can look at the documentation for [std::string](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) and [std::getline](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).